# Randomize capital letters

Tags: java, string, random

Is there a simple way to, given a word `String`, randomise capital letters?

Example:

For word `super` I would get `SuPEr` or `SUpER`.

I am looking for a Java solution for this.

Comment: Seeing as you want to _capitalize_ _random_ letters in a _string_, I would take a look at the following java documentation. java.lang.String and java.util.Random as a starting point, this problem is quite easy to solve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one suggestion:

```
public static String randomizeCase(String str) {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
        sb.append(rnd.nextBoolean()
                      ? Character.toLowerCase(c)
                      : Character.toUpperCase(c));

    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Example**

input: `hello world`
output: `heLlO woRlD`

([ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/YT1MiR))

Answer (score 1):

Treat the string as an array. So now instead of

```
string test = "Super";
```

visualize it as

```
char test = {'S', 'u' , 'p' , 'e', 'r'};
```

Now you can iterate through the array, and apply the `string.toUpperCase()` across it.